# Restart an install process

Tags: software-installation, phpmyadmin

I started installing `phpmyadmin` via SSH on an Ubuntu server and got to a question I couldn't answer and had to close. How do I resume the installation or stop it and start over?

The command `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` gives the error:

```
could not get lock [path] - open
unable to lock the administration directory
```

The command `ps aux | grep apt` gives 4 processes including `apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

BTW, the question I had was whether I should use dbconfig-common when I have existing databases. The explanation was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used SSH to connect to servers, but if I were having this problem on a local machine I would reboot to get rid of the lock problem, and then type `"sudo apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin"`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you restarted your ubuntu server to release the lock and then, try to reinstall phpmyadmin.

As a last resource you can delete the lock file, this is discussed here:
[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)